# PHP - How to sort multidimensional array by Key?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have to sort multidimensional array by key and I need some recomendation how to do it.

I tried using `ksort()` and other php built-in functions, but none of them helped me.

This is my array, which I want to sort by key:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [20190529] => Array
            (
                [30] => Array
                    (
                        [17] => Array
                            (
                                [3846] => 0
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [20190516] => Array
            (
                [31] => Array
                    (
                        [17] => Array
                            (
                                [512] => 0
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

In that case, keys are `20190529` and `20190516`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Working demo**](https://3v4l.org/Koejc).

You can use array_multisort to achieve your requirement.

```
$keys = [];
foreach($arr as $k => $item){
    $keys[] = key($item);
}
array_multisort($keys, SORT_NATURAL, $arr);
```

[array_multisort](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) — Sort multiple or multi-dimensional arrays

SORT_NATURAL - compare items as strings using "natural ordering" like [natsort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php).

Comment: thanks, I did it using my approach, but your solution very helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

I modified my array like that:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [DATE] => 20190503
        [DEAL] => 30
        [IBLOCK] => 18
        [AMOUNT] => 2500
        [PAYED] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [DATE] => 20190516
        [DEAL] => 31
        [IBLOCK] => 17
        [AMOUNT] => 512
        [PAYED] => 0
    )
)
```

then I used `usort()`:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a['DATE'] - $b['DATE'];
}

usort($mydata, "cmp");
```

And it did job for me :) but Now I have to modify my array again to return first look.

Comment: This solution helped me too. Thank you